# Need to increase value 1 by 1 in active cell within a range

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Macro5()
  Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection
      For Each cell In rng
        ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1
     Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix for your code would be

```
Sub Macro5()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("B2:B10")
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng
        cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

**Update**: By the comment I guess you would like to use the SelectionChange Event. Put the following code into the code module of the sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo EH
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("B2:B12")

    If Not (Intersect(rg, Target) Is Nothing) Then
        Dim sngCell As Range
        ' This will only increase the values of the selected cells within B2:B10
        ' Not sure if this is wanted. Otherwise just modify according to your needs
        For Each sngCell In Intersect(Target, rg)
            sngCell.Value = sngCell.Value + 1
        Next sngCell
    End If

EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Update 2**: If you want to run the code via a button put the following code into a standard module and assign it to a button you create on the sheet

```
Sub Increase()

    On Error GoTo EH
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("B2:B10")

    If Not (Intersect(rg, Selection) Is Nothing) Then
        Dim sngCell As Range
        For Each sngCell In Intersect(Selection, rg)
            sngCell.Value = sngCell.Value + 1
        Next sngCell
    End If

EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I need to increement only on active cell, eg. when I click a cell in range (B2:B10).
This increase all cells in (B2:B10)

Comment: That's not what you wrote at the beginning and even your comment is not clear for me. Which cells do you want to increase and when? It seems you would like to increase just the cell you select by 1 but only if the selected cell is within the range B2:B10, right. Please clarify.

Comment: I want when i click a cell within (B2:B10), cell value should increase 1 by 1,. Please ignore my bad English.

Comment: Better than the previous code, I want it with a button. like [Sub Increase()]. can you make it with a clickable button.

Comment: I updated the answer but you are aware that your comments contradict each other. First you want to click a cell and then the value of the cell should increase. Now you want to have a button which you click. That is not the same :-(

Answer (score 0):

Test if the current cell is within your range!

```
Sub Macro5()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim fixed_rng As Range
  Set rng = Selection
  Set fixed_rng = Range("B1:B10")
  if Application.Union(rng, fixed_rng) = fixed_rng then
    For Each cell In rng
      ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I wrote it without really testing. But I hope you get the idea. Are you getting the error on line the `Union` line? Try changing `Selection` to `Selection.Range` (or something similar).